# .Net windows form determine clicked area

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, coordinates, area

Hey all I have been trying to find some examples of being able to draw lines around an area on a form and determine if, when the user clicks on the form, if its in that drawn area or outside of it.

I see plenty of examples to get the mouse Cursor position but that's not really what I am after. I want to be able to draw the area out and have some logic behind that to determine if its within the X, Y area of the drawn lines.

If that doesn't make since above then picture making a standard HTML page with one image on it. Inside that image you have defined a "MAP" that you can either draw a rectangle, circle or polygon shape. Each area has its own coordinates and depending on where the user clicks on that image is determined by where those map coordinates are placed within that image.

HTML image map Example:

```
<img src="images/house.jpg" width="400" height="150" border="1" usemap="#home">

<map name="home">
   <area shape="circle" coords="28,126,25" href="ocotillo.html">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,86,35" href="sky.html">
   <area shape="rect" coords="271,85,329,124" href="garage.html">
   <area shape="rect" coords="141,84,176,107" href="entrance.html">
   <area shape="rect" coords="140,114,194,145" href="hitching_post.html">
   <area shape="poly" coords="182,35,225,16,280,27,282,48,190,48" href="mountain.html">
   <area shape="poly" coords="69,62,100,40,119,62,98,126" href="saguaro.html">
   <area shape="poly" coords="212,147,287,131,390,126,353,148" href="driveway">
</map>
```

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In addition to previous useful comment, your point of click can be obtained by e.location (eventargs parameter) and be passed to IsVisible methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a region out of the lines (from a graphics path, maybe), and then use the IsVisible region method to see if the mouse point lies within the region.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx